# How to check virtuemart cart empty or not

Tags: php, joomla, virtuemart

i have one question that check the virtue-mart cart, if cart is empty then page redirected to the my link such as contact page,article.

for example customer click the "order now" button but cart is empty then redirect to contact page

please help me

Comment: have you done any research on this or tried anything of your own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
$cart = VirtueMartCart::getCart();
if(sizeof($cart->products) > 0){
 echo 'Cart have products';
}
else{
 echo 'Your cart is empty';
}
```

for redirections you can use follows

```
$mainframe = JFactory::getApplication();
$mainframe->redirect('url','message','message type');//message type is message,warning,error etc
```

Hope its helps..

Comment: Glad to hear that :) next time Google first and ask question with proper tags.Also accept correct answers!